# Reverse dependencies

Tags: ivy, artifactory

We are using Ivy with Artifactory as a repository. In Artifactory both third-party libraries and our release packages are stored.

If there is a bug in an artefact (3rd party or our package) I would like to find out which other components are potentially impacted.

In short, I need a reverse dependency report.

How similar problems are usually solved?

Comment: have you tried [repreport](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.0.0/use/repreport.html)? I think it should work in both directions, but can't check it myself right now.

Comment: I tried repreport but I cannot find reverse dependency.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out Artifactory's [build integration and CI server plugins](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Build+Integration).
The plugins collect information during build time (Both CI server and build tool), manage the deployment of artifacts and finally publish a "Build Info" report containing details regarding the build environment, method, dependencies and published artifacts.

Once in Artifactory, you can view a low down of each build with links to all produced artifacts, dependencies (if they exist in the repository) and even third-party license detection.
This will be helpful in your case, since you can also view all the builds an artifact was involved in, whether as a product or a dependency.

Artifactory's tree browser can display all the builds an artifact was involved in and it applies to all artifacts, not only build products; see the screenshot in [this](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Build+Integration#BuildIntegration-RepositoryViewofBuilds) section as an example.

Artifactory's also got a [REST resource](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory%27s+REST+API#Artifactory%27sRESTAPI-BuildsforDependency) that lets you query for builds in which a certain artifact has acted as a dependency; like the tree browser viewer, this too applies to all artifacts.

Currently, plugins are available for [Jenkins](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Jenkins+%28Hudson%29+Artifactory+Plug-in), [TeamCity](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/TeamCity+Artifactory+Plug-in) and [Bamboo](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Bamboo+Artifactory+Plug-in) and they all support Maven, Ivy and Gradle builds.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. On the link you mentioned they show forward dependencies, i.e. multi.war depends on hsqldb.jar. I need reverse dependency, what modules depends on hsqldb.jar

Comment: Selecting an artifact in Artifactory's tree browser will also show you all the builds it was involved in; the screenshot in this (http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Build+Integration#BuildIntegration-RepositoryViewofBuilds) section applies to all artifacts in Artifactory.

Comment: Artifactory's also got a REST resource (http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory%27s+REST+API#Artifactory%27sRESTAPI-BuildsforDependency) that retrieves all the builds in which an artifact acted as a dependency.

Comment: I've edited my answer to clarify that fact that reverse dependencies are indeed supported.